# Rails tutorial, chapter 6 - SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

First I ran: `rails generate model User name:string email:string` and this create a migration. Later I did a `db:migrate` and I get this error:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
== 20150728195629 CreateUsers: migrating ======================================
-- create_table(:users)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: table "users" already exists.....
```

When you `generate model` the table `user` is created but then when you `rake db:migrate` it tries to create it again.

I'm confused! Am I doing something wrong?

https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#code-generate_user_model

Comment: You probably made an attempt to run a migration with a earlier version of the users table. If you want to start over again, drop the database using `rake db:drop db:create`

Comment: When you generate model the table user is created .. this is not true, only the migration is created.

Comment: Be careful when running `db:drop`, this will delete all data you may have had stored in your database

Answer (score 10):

just run into the console

```
rails console
```

and type in

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:users)
```

and then
exit the console and

```
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

You must have created a table as Marsatomic said.  Run

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate:status
```

And look at your migration history to see where you created it.  If you see it, you can roll back your migrations past that table, delete the migration file that created it, and then re-run your migrations.  If you don't see it anywhere, you must have created the table without a migration.  At that point you should do as Marsatomic instructed in his comment above.

Comment: Excelent I ran `rake db:drop db:create` and then `bundle exec rake db:migrate` and no errors this time. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'db:reset', it == 'db:drop db:create db:migrate'

Comment: Brevity is acceptable, but more detailed answer is more beneficial for the readers.

Answer (score 0):

just run into the console

```
rails db:reset
```

just run into the console

```
bundle exec rails db:migrate
```